# Не видит класс/файл в Symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony4

Уверена зная PHP стал изучать framework symfony 4.Начал с простенькой формы.При запуске сервера вылазит вот это:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**routes.yaml**:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сама ошибка связана с пространством имён.Но при добавления файла в Controller namespace автоматически его заполнял.
**Head_pageForm.php**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Вам же пишут что ищется класс по пути `\App\Form\Head_pageForm`. У вас есть такой неймспейс? Я пока что вижу `\Form\Head_pageForm`.

Comment: Спасибо.Но что мне нужно предпринять для изменения namespace?

P.S.Ведь он шёл автоматически.

Comment: Что значит - что предпринять - написать `namespace App\Form` в файле формы.

Comment: Спасибо помогло!.Думая, что правки вручную, ещё усугубят положение.Но теперь ругается :  
Class "App\Controller\Head_pageController" used for service "App\Controller\Hea
  d_pageController" cannot be found.
Как понимаю мне нужно внести его в services.yaml?

Comment: Спасибо тебе u_mulder.В конце всё разрешилась.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была решена путём изменения пространства имён(*namespase*) вместо Form на App/Form в **Head_pageForm.php** и контроллера Head_pageController, который наследовал сам себя.